# Образование глаголов и корень "каз"

Tags: этимология, словообразование

В данный момент я разбираю образование глаголов, начиная с самого первого значения корня до всевозможных выражаемых оттенков при добавке приставок и суффиксов. Я заметил, что корень ***каз*** очень продуктивный, но глагол ***казать*** уже не существует в современном языке. Кто знает откуда он и что он значит?

Comment: Добрый день, Александр! Интересный момент: я вчера только понял, что во французском ставят пробелы перед многими знаками препинания, а также перед и после кавычек. Не ставят пробелов только перед точкой, запятой, и скобки примыкают к тексту. Верно я понял? А вот в русском не ставят пробелов и перед остальными знаками (у Вас лишний пробел после **;** и **?**). А вот после всех знаков препинания пробелы не надо забывать как раз ставить. Не надо, если текст идёт после многоточия (цитируется не сначала смыслового отрывка). Больше вроде не припомню... Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ !

Comment: Артём , ставят пробел перед и после знаков препинания когда тот знак состоит из двух знака (  ; : ! ? ... () "" )

Comment: А-а! Но скобки же не отделяют пробелами ведь!

Comment: Непонятной у меня получилась фраза насчёт многоточия: "не надо" не забывать, конечно, а не нужен пробел. Не перечитал, что написал, и получилось не очень складно в итоге. :(

Answer (score 1):

﻿

**КАЗА́ТЬ**, кажу, кажешь; несовер., кого (что) (прост.).
То же, что показывать (в 1 знач.). Казать обновы.
• **Не казать глаз (носу)** (разг.) не показываться, не появляться.

Толковый словарь Ожегова ([**и другие словари**](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&newwindow=1&ei=Wag2WsCxCMfKwAKywJeQDA&start=0&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=651))

**каза́ть**
кажу́: вы́казать, показа́ть, сказа́ть, отказа́ть, приказа́ть, также ука́з, прика́з, расска́з и т. д., укр. каза́ти "говорить", ст.-слав. казати, (...) в.-луж. kazać "показывать, называть", н.-луж. kazaś.

Вероятно предположение о чередовании и.-е. ǵ и ḱ в конце к. (ср. греч. δίκη "предначертание, указание"; δεῖγμα "доказательство" и т. д.) и родстве с др.-инд. kā́c̨atē "появляется, блистает, светит", ākāc̨ya "увидел", авест. ākasat̃ "увидел", нов.-перс. āgāh "сведущий", далее: др.-инд. cáṣṭē "появляется, видит"...
[**М. Фасмер. Этимологический словарь русского языка**](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-4615.htm)

*Себя **казать**, как чудный зверь,

В Петрополь едет он теперь

С запасом фраков и жилетов.*
А. Пушкин. Граф Нулин

*Рюмка **кажет** донышко, Борзятников обсасывает обмокшие в вине усы, крякает, делает лицо притворно трагическим.*
В. Шишков. Угрюм-река

Нельзя говорить, что глагол "казать" уже не существует в русском языке.
Правильным, скорее, будет утверждение: употребляется редко, в определенном контексте (просторечный).

Answer (score 1):

Два источника на заметку:

http://www.slavdict.ru/_0241.htm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и Краткий этимологический словарь русского языка. — H.M. Шанский, В.В. Иванов, Т.В. Шанская, 1971 г.

КАЗА́ТЬСЯ. В памятниках отмечается с XI в. Образовано посредством присоединения возвратной частицы -ся от общеславянского казати, имеющего ту же основу, что др.-инд. cáṣṭē — «видит, усматривает».